# Are there CPAN modules that will help me parse an RSS or ATOM feed in Perl?

Tags: perl, rss, cpan, atom-feed

I need code in Perl for requesting and parsing ATOM and RSS feeds. Is there a CPAN module(s) for that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[XML::FeedPP](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=XML%3A%3AFeedPP+++%09+&mode=all) is good ...

Comment: Beware of at least http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/pkgreport.cgi?pkg=libxml-feedpp-perl;dist=unstable but it's the best thats out there, AFAIK.

Answer (score 16):

Almost any time that you ask "How can I do X in Perl?", the answer is to look at [CPAN Search](http://search.cpan.org) to find the module that does it.

To download from the web, the [LWP](http://search.cpan.org/dist/libwww-perl) family of modules can help you. To parse the documents, try something with [Feed](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=Feed&mode=all), [RSS](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=RSS&mode=all), or [Atom](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=Atom&mode=all) in the name.

Four years later, though, I now recommend [Mojolicious](https://www.metacpan.org/module/Mojolicious), which has its own user agent module  and very strong support for DOM parsing and the various ways to pull out parts of a document. Depending on what you want, you probably don't need a special feed module anymore.

Comment: Brian, this isn't as helpful as you might hope in this case: searching for 'RSS' and a few other terms tends to get you writers, plugins for other tools and old, dead modules and any signal in there is drowned out by noise.

Comment: @ijw: spend more than 3 minutes trying.

Comment: I would like to see a "popularity" or "downloads" sort in the CPAN Search (and PPM) like Nuget has http://nuget.org/packages It's not a bad proxy for "how good is this module?".

Comment: Try [MetaCPAN](https://www.metacpan.org) for ++ on modules. That doesn't mean anything about quality though. :)

Answer (score 4):

Both [XML::RSS](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-RSS) and [XML::Atom](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Atom) exist. Be warned -- XML::Atom does not seem to be actively maintained and reportedly has bugs. But the basics should be enough to get you going.

To fetch the feeds LWP::Simple is a good choice.

Comment: XML::RSS is primarily used to generate RSS files but it also has `parse()` methods to read RSS.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that [XML::Feed](http://search.cpan.org/~simonw/XML-Feed/) does a much better job of dealing with the errors that you **are** going to get if you're trying to parse arbitrary feeds that you don't control the generation of.

Comment: I've used the XML::FeedPP version of XML::Feed to great effect.